# Resizing MonoTouch.Dialog StyledMultilineElement after an async call

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm playing with MonoTouch.Dialog and written some code to show some tweets. The problem is that the table cells are too small and the cells are all bunched up when I load the `StyledMultilineElement`s *asynchronously*. They look absolutely perfect when I load them synchronously (i.e. without the `QueueUserWorkItem`/`InvokeOnMainThread` part)

Is there a way of getting the table cells to recalculate their height?

```
// This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{           
    window.AddSubview(navigation.View);

    var tweetsSection = new Section("MonoTouch Tweets"){
        new StringElement("Loading...") //placeholder
    };

    var menu = new RootElement("Demos"){
        tweetsSection,
    };

    var dv = new DialogViewController(menu) { Autorotate = true };
    navigation.PushViewController(dv, true);                

    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    // Load tweets async
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23MonoTouch");
        var atom = (XNamespace)"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

        var tweets = 
            from node in doc.Root.Descendants(atom + "entry")
            select new { 
                Author = node.Element(atom + "author").Element(atom + "name").Value, 
                Text =  node.Element(atom + "title").Value
            };
        var newElements = 
                from tweet in tweets
                select new StyledMultilineElement(
                    tweet.Author, 
                    tweet.Text);

        InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
            tweetsSection.Remove(0);                                    
            tweetsSection.Add(newElements.Cast<Element>().ToList());    
        });
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `UnevenRows` property on your top level `Root` element of your Dialog View Controller, in this case "menu":

```
menu.UnevenRows = true
```

Comment: Cheers Miguel that along with tweaking the GetHeight code did the trick. I shall submit a pull request for the latter.